# Measure Hadoop job time using JobControl

Tags: hadoop, jobs, timing

I used to launch my Hadoop job with the following

```
long start = new Date().getTime();
boolean status = job.waitForCompletion(true);            
long end = new Date().getTime();
```

This way I could measure the time taken by the job once it ends directly in my code.

Now I have to use the JobControl in order to express dependencies between my jobs:

```
JobControl jobControl = new JobControl("MyJob");
jobControl.addJob(job1);
jobControl.addJob(job2);
job3.addDependingJob(job2);
jobControl.addJob(job3);

jobControl.run();
```

However once jobControl.run() has been executed, the code never goes further so I cannot include code to poll on the jobControl.getState() for the completion of the job.

How can I measure the time taken by a job using JobControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JobControl has no nice functionality to allow you to hook and get this information. You have some (potentially painful) options to try:

- Start `JobControl.run()` in a separate thread, and in your main thread, poll the `JobControl.getXXXJobs()` methods to track when jobs change state
- Look into using the [Job End Notification URL hook](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html#setJobEndNotificationURI%28java.lang.String%29), but this will require you to start a 'server' in your client to receive the notification events, and then try to work backwards from when a job ends
- Extend the `JobControl` and `jobcontrol.Job` objects to track when a job changes state and add methods to query the start / end times